# How to get a pointer to each argument after each commandline option, using GETOPT

Tags: c, linux, unix, pointers, getopt

Command line input of the form:

```
exeName -a argumentA -b argumentB -c argumentC
```

Need to extract each argument into a corresponding variable (i.e. int a = argumentA, etc).

Appears the function getop() is used to find command line options.

However, I don't see how I can get a pointer to after each option (so I can pull the argument after it).

This reference from the man page sounds like it.... but not much info on how to use it:

> "If getopt() finds another option character, it returns that
>   character, updating the external variable optind and a static variable
>   nextchar"

How can I use getop() to set a pointer to the argument after each command line option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optarg` gives pointer to the current options that was scanned by [getopt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getopt.html). If you want pointer to each argument passed on the commandline, then you can store in them in an array of pointers, given by `optarg`.

Here's a minimal working example:

#include 
 #include

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *p = 0;
  char *arr[5] = {0};
  int i;
  int c;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "A:B:C:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'A':
      arr[0] = optarg; 
      break;
    case 'B':
      arr[1] = optarg;
      break;
    case 'C':
      arr[2] = optarg;
      break;
    default:
      printf("Invalid option %c\n", c);
    }

  printf("A:%s B:%s C:%s", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);    
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, you should add more error checking when one or more of the options are not provided.

Comment: is the getopt_long used for options that are longer than 1 char? For example: exe -abc argumentABC -def argumentDEF ?

Comment: No. getopt() doesn't support more than single char. If you have different requirements, you could implement it the argument parsing yourself: Loop through the array `argv[]` and do `strcmp()` on expected option(s) and then get the next string which is the argument for that option.

Comment: "To accept GNU-style long options as well as single-character options". I think this is the one to do that: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options

Comment: getopt_long() is for long options such as `--help` which may be mapped to something simple such `-h`. Here's [an example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html). But this doesn't do exactly what you want.

Comment: yeah, that is the one I was looking at.... I wonder if the long option has to be in the form -- and if one dash will also work...or if there is an option to only look for one dash.

Comment: doesn't look like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877368/getopt-passing-string-parameter-for-argument

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the manpage:

> [If ... the option requires an argument] getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element,  in **`optarg`**.

`optarg` appears in the header file `unistd.h`, which (also according to the manpage) includes:

```
int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[],
              const char *optstring);

extern char *optarg;
extern int optind, opterr, optopt;
```

In other words, it is a global variable updated by a call to `getopt` which encounters an option with an argument.

Comment: thank you, and after running it, it is important to note that EACH option that will have a argument needs to have a colon in the option list, as shown in Blue Moon's example....