# command-line argument of "−" when making standard unix programs for C

Tags: c, unix

removeC.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            if(c != 'c') {
                putchar(c);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if(argv[1][i] != 'c') {
                putchar(argv[1][i]);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

removeC.c removes every c in a file then prints it to stdout. For example,

```
$ gcc -Wall removeC.c
$ ./a.out abc
ab
$ echo abc | ./a.out
ab
$ ./a.out file1
ab
```

assuming file1's contents is also 'abc'

The goal is to make it work like standard Unix tools (but it's allowed to not take any command line options, i.e "./a.out -w somefile").

How do I deal with command-line argument of "−"?

Comment: I didn't test, but it looks like your code reads stdin if you do not provide an argument.  Therefore, try this: `cat file1 | ./a.out`

Comment: Take a look at the man page for `getopt`.

Comment: `getopt` is your answer it is very well documented, but you can look here for a start point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877368/getopt-passing-string-parameter-for-argument

Comment: Your `argc != 2` condition covers no arguments, but also many arguments.  You should distinguish carefully between those cases; you should (almost certainly) handle `./a.out` and `./a.out *` quite differently.

Comment: The snarky answer would be that `−` (U+2212 MINUS SIGN) is treated as any other file name. (The quoted character in the question is U+2212, not U+002D or ASCII `-`.) Most POSIXy/UNIXy applications only treat `--` specially: all following arguments are treated as file names, even if they begin with a dash `-` (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS). As others have mentioned, some applications treat `-` as a name for standard input; this is not a problem even if you happen to have a file named `-`, because you can always refer to it using a relative path, for example `./-`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, Unix utilities interpret an argument consisting solely of `-` to be equivalent to `stdin` if it could be interpreted as an input file, or as equivalent to `stdout` if it definitely would be interpreted as an output file.

In this case it would be an input file if it were a named file, so it would normally be equivalent to `stdin`.

This is Guideline #13 of the Posix [Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

> #### Guideline 13:
>
> For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the `-` operand should be used to mean only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified) or a file named `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite easily with a simple *ternary* operator and checking `argv[1]`. While this presumes you do not have other options beginning with `'-'`, you can easily adapt it for that case with `getopt`. This is quite a handy "quick and dirty" setup for flexibly reading input from either a file or `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c;
    /* read from filename given as argv[1], or stdin by default or '-' */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 && *argv[1] != '-' ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* output reading from ... */
    printf ("reading from '%s'\n", fp == stdin ? "stdin" : argv[1]);

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)     /* read until EOF */
        putchar (c);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/dog.txt
my dog has fleas
```

**Example Use/Output**

Read from `stdin` without `'-'`,

```
$ echo "my dog has fleas" | ./bin/unix_read_file_or_stdin
reading from 'stdin'
my dog has fleas
```

Read from `stdin` with `'-'`,

```
$ echo "my dog has fleas" | ./bin/unix_read_file_or_stdin -
reading from 'stdin'
my dog has fleas
```

Read from `stdin` using redirection from file,

```
$ ./bin/unix_read_file_or_stdin <dat/dog.txt
reading from 'stdin'
my dog has fleas
```

Read from file,

```
$ ./bin/unix_read_file_or_stdin dat/dog.txt
reading from 'dat/dog.txt'
my dog has fleas
```

This is not a substitute for a full `getopt` implementation, but is handy for small utilities.